# Issue with Particle JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing issue for implementing particle JS.
I added two JS files but not getting any output in browser.
Here is my code.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>particles.js</title>
  <meta name="description" content="particles.js is a lightweight JavaScript library for creating particles.">
  <meta name="author" content="Vincent Garreau" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body id="particles-js" bgcolor="#000000">
<!-- count particles -->
<!-- particles.js container -->
<!-- scripts -->
<script src="js/particles.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, particles JS is instanciated by writing a few lines of Javascript. Could we see your Javascript please ? Second of all, you should not apply it to the body. Create a container that will be the size of the body, but isn't the body itself.

Comment: what's the expected Output? @Shelly Beth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is issue with your body tag.
there is nothing inside body tag.
also there is no css that define width and height of webpage.
what you can do is create another division inside body and add ID to that div.
see below code.

```js
particlesJS("particles-js", {"particles":{"number":{"value":80,"density":{"enable":true,"value_area":800}},"color":{"value":"#ffffff"},"shape":{"type":"circle","stroke":{"width":0,"color":"#000000"},"polygon":{"nb_sides":5},"image":{"src":"img/github.svg","width":100,"height":100}},"opacity":{"value":0.5,"random":false,"anim":{"enable":false,"speed":1,"opacity_min":0.1,"sync":false}},"size":{"value":3,"random":true,"anim":{"enable":false,"speed":40,"size_min":0.1,"sync":false}},"line_linked":{"enable":true,"distance":150,"color":"#ffffff","opacity":0.4,"width":1},"move":{"enable":true,"speed":6,"direction":"none","random":false,"straight":false,"out_mode":"out","bounce":false,"attract":{"enable":false,"rotateX":600,"rotateY":1200}}},"interactivity":{"detect_on":"canvas","events":{"onhover":{"enable":true,"mode":"repulse"},"onclick":{"enable":true,"mode":"push"},"resize":true},"modes":{"grab":{"distance":400,"line_linked":{"opacity":1}},"bubble":{"distance":400,"size":40,"duration":2,"opacity":8,"speed":3},"repulse":{"distance":200,"duration":0.4},"push":{"particles_nb":4},"remove":{"particles_nb":2}}},"retina_detect":true});var count_particles, stats, update; stats = new Stats; stats.setMode(0); stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute'; stats.domElement.style.left = '0px'; stats.domElement.style.top = '0px'; document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement); count_particles = document.querySelector('.js-count-particles'); update = function() { stats.begin(); stats.end(); if (window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles && window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array) { count_particles.innerText = window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array.length; } requestAnimationFrame(update); }; requestAnimationFrame(update);;
```

```css
/* ---- reset ---- */ body{ margin:0; font:normal 75% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; } canvas{ display: block; vertical-align: bottom; } /* ---- particles.js container ---- */ #particles-js{ position:absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #b61924; background-image: url(""); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%; } /* ---- stats.js ---- */ .count-particles{ background: #000022; position: absolute; top: 48px; left: 0; width: 80px; color: #13E8E9; font-size: .8em; text-align: left; text-indent: 4px; line-height: 14px; padding-bottom: 2px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; } .js-count-particles{ font-size: 1.1em; } #stats, .count-particles{ -webkit-user-select: none; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 5px; } #stats{ border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0; overflow: hidden; } .count-particles{ border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px; }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<!-- particles.js container --> <div id="particles-js"></div> <!-- stats - count particles --> <div class="count-particles"> <span class="js-count-particles">--</span> particles </div> <!-- particles.js lib - https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js --> 
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```